# Device drivers: how do I get programmatic access to the actual pins/hardware?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, gpio

If you don't think this question is constructed properly, please see its original version. I have been asked to reduce this question to its minimal form.

If I'm writing a Linux device driver, how do I get programmatic access to actual GPIO pins? For example:

```
// Turn a green LED on by sending the GPIO pins 0x11223344
int cmd = encode(Commands.TURN_GREEN_ON);
send_to_gpio_pins(cmd);
```

Again, if this is unclear, it's because I'm trying to oblige community rules for keeping it simple, stupid. In that case read my first version of this question.

Comment: I've controlled my impulse to edit out everything but the main question. Instead, you ought to consider doing that yourself. Also, consider changing the title to the question.

Comment: Nocturno, hope the edit reads better, although I worry that now I'm going to be answering a lot of "need more info" type followup questions/comments. That's the tradeoff...

Comment: IMO using GPIO to communicate between two computer systems is a bad idea. You are trying to immediately implement something without evaluating protocol requirements.  Is this supposed to be master-slave connection?  You need to define such basic assumptions.  Any interface you construct will be processor-to-processor; you cannot remotely control the GPIO of another device.  For control of userland access to local GPIO, some people use *sysfs* instead of using a device driver.

Comment: @HeineyBehinds Much better, thanks.

Comment: Interesting.  In order to "keep it simple", the question has now evolved into an XY problem (although this revised question does have merit, since it is answerable).

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_Code_examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Linux device driver should have access to a set of functions provided by the arch's *gpio* module.  Since I am familiar with Atmel ARM code and not sure about the Broadcom SoC used by the RPI, here's some real *gpio* code.

I/O devices on ARM SoCs are typically memory mapped (i.e. there is no separate I/O address space).  These physical addresses can be mapped into kernel virtual address space. (The addresses of a peripheral's registers are often mapped by the individual device driver for its exclusive use.)
Once mapped into virtual memory, registers that contain or control the state of a GPIO pin can simply be accessed by an ordinary read or write memory operation (while conforming to C language requirements).  Consult the [Broadcom SoC hardware document](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) for the exact assignment/functionality of each bit in these device registers.

Prior to using a GPIO as either an input pin or an output pin, the GPIO pin must be configured.  Often the pin will have multiple uses (it's "multiplexed"), so one of those specific functionalities has to be selected during *early board initilization*.  These assignments are performed by writing to device configuration registers (which are mapped to memory locations).

An Atmel function to write the value of a GPIO pin (from [arch/arm/mach-at91/gpio.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-at91/gpio.c)) :

```
/*
 * assuming the pin is muxed as a gpio output, set its value.
 */
int at91_set_gpio_value(unsigned pin, int value)
{
        void __iomem    *pio = pin_to_controller(pin);
        unsigned        mask = pin_to_mask(pin);

        if (!pio)
                return -EINVAL;
        __raw_writel(mask, pio + (value ? PIO_SODR : PIO_CODR));
        return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(at91_set_gpio_value);
```

An Atmel function to read the value of a GPIO pin:

```
/*
 * read the pin's value (works even if it's not muxed as a gpio).
 */
int at91_get_gpio_value(unsigned pin)
{
        void __iomem    *pio = pin_to_controller(pin);
        unsigned        mask = pin_to_mask(pin);
        u32             pdsr;

        if (!pio)
                return -EINVAL;
        pdsr = __raw_readl(pio + PIO_PDSR);
        return (pdsr & mask) != 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(at91_get_gpio_value);
```

Hopefully you can find similar code in the kernel that you use (e.g. *grep* the `System.map` symbol file for "gpio").